# Cloning my Windows forms custom control arguably works, but I can't see the clone

Tags: .net, vb.net, custom-controls, clone

I am trying to clone my Windows Form custom control.

In it, I have

```
Public Class UFB
    Implements ICloneable

    ...

    Public Function Clone() As Object Implements ICloneable.Clone
        'Copy this instance's properties.
        Dim oClone As New UFB With {
            .BackColor = Me.BackColor,
            'Another few dozen properties.
            ... }

        'Deep copy of objects in a dictionary (loop).
        ...

        Return oClone
    End Function

    ...
End Class
```

The Windows Form using this has a command button to clone. The object to be cloned is named `cFlb`.

I use it like this:

```
Public Class FMain
    Dim WithEvents cFlbClone As UFB

    Private Sub Clone()
        cFlbClone = CType(cFlb.Clone, UFB)

        cFlbClone.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Yellow    'Make it distinguishable.
        cFlbClone.Visible = True
        cFlb.Visible = False
    End Sub
End Class
```

Compiles well in both projects.

A breakpoint on `cFlb.Visible = False` let's me inspect the `cFlb` properties. All is there as it should be, especially also the deep copy elements. The position of the clone is the same as the original's.

The only problem I have: I don't see the clone. There's simply nothing.

What do I miss?

Comment: The position is the same, but how about the size?

Comment: Anyway, create a [mcve] with a simple form and 1 or 2 controls.

Comment: Did you clone the Parent property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a control to be visible, it must be *parented* to either the Form or another control that that has the form as its [TopLevelControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.toplevelcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx).  If any ancestor control is not visible, the subject control will also not be visible.

The can be accomplished either by setting the control's [Parent Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.parent(v=vs.110).aspx) or adding the control to the parent control's [Controls Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls(v=vs.110).aspx).